# Issue with model, not solid at one end

Tags: objects

I am new to Blender and using it to create some very simple scenery for *Microsoft Flight Simulator X: Steam Edition*.

I created a heli dam with the cylinder mesh, set the thickness of my walls and used the extrude command to move the face of the cylinder down but left a gap between the outer face and the inner face.

I then shaped my model, assigned materials and textured it, but the bottom of my model is not solid and shows the ground textures.

Just wondering if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I'm wondering how you expect us to help you without seeing any screenshots, or geometry/topology, or the blend file https://blend-exchange.com :D

Comment: I suspect you have inverted normals, try to select all in Edit mode and Shift N in order to recalculate the normals